# Ionic/Angular Pushing object to Array Object

Tags: angular, object, ionic-framework

I am trying to push an Object with values to an `Array` but I always get `null` is not an object in the console. But when I `console.log` the object it is filled and not `null` so why can't I push it into the array?

```
            let obj: Lektion;
            obj = {
                LektionID: data2.string[0],
                Date: data2.string[1],
                StudentID: data2.string[2],
                Name: data2.string[3],
                Status: (data2.string[4] !== '0'),
                TeacherID: data2.string[5]
            };
            console.log(obj);
            this.Lektionen.push(obj);
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Fx9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got confuse on variable and interface. `Lektion` is an interface define it's as a variable and try to push it into that.

```
   let Lektionen = [];
    const data2= {string:[1,2,3,4,5,6]};

    let obj:Lektion = {
                LektionID: data2.string[0],
                Date: data2.string[1],
                StudentID: data2.string[2],
                Name: data2.string[3],
                Status: (data2.string[4] !== '0'),
                TeacherID: data2.string[5]
            };
            this.Lektionen.push(obj);

            console.log(Lektionen); //will print the object
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized this.Lektionen? Try initializing it prior pushing the object.

```
this.Lektionen = [];
this.Lektionen.push(obj);
```

Ideally, initialize it where you have declared the variable or in the function where you are going to push items in the array.